# Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE and Log path

Tags: spring-boot

We have a Spring boot application which uses logback-spring.xml to configure several appenders. To specify the location to store the log files we use `LOG_PATH`, which was using the application property logging.path. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging)
In version `2.3.0` the logging.path is deprecated, and has changed to logging.file.path. 
Is `LOG_PATH` still usable and now using `logging.file.path` or do we need to change `LOG_PATH` to `LOG_FILE_PATH?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the variable ${LOG_PATH} inside the logback.xml/logback-spring.xml is still the same. As you already mentioned, you just have to change to logging.file.path inside your application.properties file.

The link to the updated documentation for the 2.3.0 version is: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/howto.html#howto-logging